# Getting a list of commits/commit history from AWS CodeCommit repo

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codecommit

Is it possible right now, programatically to get a list of commits on an AWS CodeCommit repository?

I understand I can use the git command, but I am trying to get the repository information by using CodeCommit's API. Is that possible, or des the API not exist?

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
aws codecommit get-branch --repository-name MyRepo --branch-name MyBranch
```

In order to get the commit ID of the branch.

Then you can call:

```
aws codecommit get-commit --repository-name MyRepo --commitId MyCommitID
```

to get the comment, author and parent commit ID.
Iterating through the parent IDs you can get the history.

Answer (score 3):

An API to directly get commit history is not currently available.

As a general rule, we don't comment on the future direction of the service, but we'd be interested in hearing the details of your use case.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I disagree, it answers the question "Is there an API" with "No".

Comment: Well, its more like using the git log command to see the list of commits to a file. If our server is failing, perhaps take a look at who committed what. The getCommit needs a commitID which seems tedious