# AWS CodeCommit - Is it is it possible to retrieve the commit list of PR?

Tags: javascript, git, pull-request, aws-codecommit

As in the topic, I would like to retrieve the committ list of a given pull request using AWS CodeCommit SDK in JavaScript. Is it at all possible?

Answer (score 0):

That does not seem available ([same as in 2016](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37757532/6309)) in the [AWS CodeCommit API Reference.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html)

Nothing in what is returned with [View pull requests (AWS CLI)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/how-to-view-pull-request.html#how-to-view-pull-request-cli) would return the list of commits.
The API allows to merge two branches... but not to compare them.